# About the isothermal compression and thermal expansion and his relation with the van der Waals equation

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, physical-chemistry, gas

In my class notes I see this postulate about the isothermal compression, I try to prove that the statement is true, but I can´t figure it out, I only ask for ideas or some references where I can search this identity, thanks!

The next differentials (dV, dp) are exact differentials:
$$\frac{dV}{V}=\beta dT-\kappa_{T}dp$$
$$dp=\frac{\beta}{\kappa_{T}}dT -\frac{1}{V\kappa_{T}}dV$$

Then the next equation holds:

$$(\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial V})_{T}=\beta (\frac{\partial \ln \kappa_{T}}{\partial V})_{T}+(\frac{1}{V})(\frac{\partial \ln \kappa_{T}}{\partial T})_{V}$$

Where $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})_z$ means that the z parameter is treated as a constant.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here. What is the result you want to derive?

Comment: I want to prove that the last questions holds (I mean, that the partial of B respecto to V when T is constant is equal to the sum of the partials) when dV and dp are exact differentials.

Answer (score 0):

From the previous equation, it follows that $$\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial V\partial T}=\left(\frac{\partial (\beta/\kappa)}{\partial V}\right)_T=-\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\frac{1}{V\kappa}\right)_V$$